# How to insert JSON tweets from Twitter Streaming API in MongoDB using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, twitter, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Everything seems to work just fine but it think the code skips the saving part here?

`var TwitterData = new User(obj); // create object
 TwitterData.save(); // save data to DB`.

Or maybe I just wrote something wrong because `console.log(obj);` seems to be working fine and it outputs the JSON tweets in the console. Also, the tweets that I am saving does not always have consistent attributes since some tweets contain geo coordinates while others dont. Here is my code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Twit = require('twit')

var T = new Twit({
  consumer_key: '',
  consumer_secret: '',
  access_token: '',
  access_token_secret: ''
})

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// create a schema
var userSchema = new Schema({}, {"strict": false});

// the schema is useless so far
// we need to create a model using it
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

// make this available to our users in our Node applications
module.exports = User;

var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: 'travel' })

stream.on('tweet', function (obj) {

  var TwitterData = new User(obj); // create object 
  TwitterData.save(); // save data to DB
  console.log(obj);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It was so dumb of me to forget to connect to the database first with this code `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/insert_sample');` -_-